# filtering a 2D array in javascript, i tried everything

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, duplicates

I have 2D array like this :

```
[[ONE,1],[QUARTER,0.25],[QUARTER,0.25]]
```

I want it to become :

```
[[ONE,1],[QUARTER,0.5]]
```

I tried using array.IndexOf but no luck

```
ONE,1,QUARTER,0.25,QUARTER,0.25
```

Comment: Post what you've tried. Who knows, you could be really close to the answer!

Comment: do you want the same array, or a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to your question title, your example suggests you want **sum**, as opposed to filter, the array.

```js
let arr = [['ONE', 1], ['QUARTER', 0.25], ['QUARTER', 0.25]];

let sums = arr.reduce((sums, item) => {
  let found = sums.find(([key]) => key === item[0]);
  if (found)
    found[1] += item[1];
  else
    sums.push(item);
  return sums;
}, []);

console.log(sums);
```

Comment: hello, your code works great on everything except on my program, so i know i must've made a mistake here, can you take a quick look please, I tried everything and coudn't find whats wrong:
https://github.com/Hasan-Alsulaiman/cash-register.git

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array by looking if the same key exists.

```js
var array = [['ONE', 1], ['QUARTER', 0.25], ['QUARTER', 0.25]],
    result = array.reduce((r, [key, value]) => {
        var temp = r.find(a => a[0] === key);
        if (temp) {
            temp[1] += value;
        } else {
            r.push([key, value]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```